# How to edit a ListView row programmatically?

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I need to edit the values of an existing ListView row (i.e change the values of an Item and its Subitems).

I need to do that programmatically and not by clicking on the ListView item at runtime to rename it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use [LVM_SETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as documented.

Comment: Isn't `LVM_SETITEM` used to insert a new Subitem?

Comment: `LVM_SETITEM` is also for updating. Or use the macro `ListView_SetItemText(hwnd, row, column, "text"); ` if you just want to change text.